# why does my smoke animation shown in the viewport shading but not shown in the render shading

Tags: smoke-simulation

this is the tutorial that I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8lHVnQdtSA&t=615s
I did everything on the blender 2.8, but I did not see the buttom that enables the volumetric render, and I dont know if that is my part of the problem.
Here is some setting that I took, and the screen that shows the volumetric render option but not the buttom that can enable it
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the text in the attribute node, but in my opinion if you use Blender 2.8, instead of using the old way, you can try the new way using new volume shader, Principled Volume Shader
[image]